# Experimental design table in R

Tags: r

How can I generate the following experimental design table in R?

[image]

Comment: You are looking for a design matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make use of a nice trick connected with binary representations of consecutive integers (I assume you do not wish to generate a row with zeros only):

```
n <- 4
M <- matrix(NA_integer_, nrow=2^n-1, ncol=n)
for (i in 1:(2^n-1))
   M[i, ] <- as.integer(intToBits(i)[1:n])
print(M)
```

which gives for `n==4`:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    1    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0
 [5,]    1    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    1    0
 [7,]    1    1    1    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    1
 [9,]    1    0    0    1
[10,]    0    1    0    1
[11,]    1    1    0    1
[12,]    0    0    1    1
[13,]    1    0    1    1
[14,]    0    1    1    1
[15,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks for introduce the function intToBits. i searched online that it means a function that returns a raw vector of 32 times the length of an integer vector with entries 0 and 1. As i am statistics major student without computer science knowledge. May you tell me how exactly it means? Thanks again for your gentle help.

Comment: Each integer number may be represented in different bases. What we are accustomed to (contemporarily, but the history of mathematics knows other examples) are decimal, e.g. base-10 numbers, e.g. 123 means 3*10^0 + 2*10^1 + 1*10^2 (10 is the base here). However, we may also write the same integer as a base-2 (binary) number by finding b_0, ..., b_k in {0,1} such that 123 = sum_{i=0}^k b_i*2^k. The space for comment is too short, so I may recommend you reading e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) or [this](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html).

Comment: Anyway, the trick used to generate the design table bases on noting that such a table consists of binary representations (each digit in a different column) of consecutive integers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want every combination except 0 0 0 0.

```
> # create all combinations of 4 0s/1s
> design <- expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1)
> design
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     0    0    0    0
2     1    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0
4     1    1    0    0
5     0    0    1    0
6     1    0    1    0
7     0    1    1    0
8     1    1    1    0
9     0    0    0    1
10    1    0    0    1
11    0    1    0    1
12    1    1    0    1
13    0    0    1    1
14    1    0    1    1
15    0    1    1    1
16    1    1    1    1
> # remove the single run you don't want
> design[-1,]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
2     1    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0
4     1    1    0    0
5     0    0    1    0
6     1    0    1    0
7     0    1    1    0
8     1    1    1    0
9     0    0    0    1
10    1    0    0    1
11    0    1    0    1
12    1    1    0    1
13    0    0    1    1
14    1    0    1    1
15    0    1    1    1
16    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Actually it looks like your design is missing an additional row on top of 0 0 0 0 but I don't care enough to figure out which one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i missed 1 0 1 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to analyze factorial designs in R, you're better off using one of the [many DoE packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html). For instance, the [`DoE.base`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DoE.base/DoE.base.pdf) package has a function, `fac.design(...)` which does essentially what you want:

```
library(DoE.base)
df <- fac.design(nlevels=2,nfactors=4,randomize=F, 
                 factor.names=list(0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1))
```

As pointed out in another answer, your design is a full factorial, except that is it missing two of the combinations (which makes me wonder if it's a factorial design at all...).